# How to save binary data from MS SQL with php

Tags: php, sql-server, blob

Good day everybody. I have a some problem with downloading data from MS SQL. 
When I try download file from varbinary field in standard ways I get string in a browser like: ***string(26567) 504B0304400600080002100F021EC....*** and when I using function `fopen` and then `fwrite` data which I get from query just write it like a string inside a document or PDF' file and I can't open it . 
This code I using. [[code sourse]](http://ideone.com/e.js/2SjDDG)

When I try solving this question on my local web server (***OpenServer with MySQL and php 5.6***)  I have get a successful result, all files from testing blob field are downloading correct and after that I can open them in a their programs.
And if I write `var_dump($file)` in a browser I see this *�PNG IHDRA)y��sRGB���gAMA*

But if I try to repeat it at Windows OS(***IIS 7 + MS SQL 2008 R2 + php 5.6.30***) I getting a file (*for example: text.doc*) with correct size (*for ex: 29Kb*) but inside there is a long string on 850 pages. And if I write `var_dump($file);` in a browser I see this *string(49370) 504B0304400600080002100F021EC..*

Maybe someone faced this problem?

Comment: Look at line 5 in your sample code, pretty sure that's not going to work as intended:   *$q->binndColumn(1, $name); *       As far as what is happening to your data,  that does the table and fields look like in your MS SQL server instance?  Are you using the same data types?  MySQL and MS SQL are not equally tolerant to typing (MySQL is more loose than MS SQL).

Comment: @DDeMartini When I use a MySQL database I choose the _blob_ field, on MS SQL uses _varbinary(max)_. But when I change field type (_on varbinary with size 65000_) in MySQL db and upload file there, after that I can download this file and open it. About parameter `$q->bindColumn` - it's work correctly, I check it use `var_dump("name")` and get _**text.doc**_

Comment: Your sample code is:   "$q->binndColumn(1, $name);"    and I don't know if the code you're using has the syntax error or not, just saying you might look at that.   As far as the data, I'm not sure blob and varbinary are equivalent enough for what you are trying.  MS SQL docs say  varbinary maxes out at 8k.  Check the len() or size of the data you're getting back from MS SQL and see if it is the same or close to what you are getting from your MySQL test.  That might shed some light on things.